# Show that $\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-3)} = -3\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-1)^n}{2^{n+2}} - \frac{1}{2(z-1)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Show that $\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-3)} = -3\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-1)^n}{2^{n+2}} - \frac{1}{2(z-1)}$.

I tried breaking it up using partial fractions but it did not seem to get me any closer to what I want.

Comment: Your sum is missing a $z$. As is, it's wrong.

Comment: whoops. thanks. I fixed it and put what it was really supposed to say.

Comment: Hint: $z-3=z-1-2=2(\frac{z-1}{2}-1)$

Comment: The sum still is wrong, or better: incompletely expressed, if we don't assume something about $\;|z-1|;$ ...

Comment: Sorry. Would it help if I said that $0 < |z-1| < 2$?

Comment: Yes it does, @StefanSmith: it has the summand $\;-\frac1{2(z-1)}$

Comment: @DonAntonio : Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac z{(z-1)(z-3)}=-\frac1{2(z-1)}+\frac3{2(z-3)}=-\frac1{2(z-1)}-\frac34\frac1{1-\frac{z-1}2}\;\;(**)$$

Now, we have that

$$|z-1|<2\implies \frac{|z-1|}2<1\;,\;\;\text{so}$$

$$(**)=-\frac1{2(z-1)}-\frac34\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(z-1)^n}{2^n}=-3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z-1)^n}{2^{n+2}}-\frac1{2(z-1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the series on the right-hand side is a geometric series.  The value of a geometric series is $\frac{\mbox{First Term in Series}}{1-\mbox{Common Ratio}}$.  The first term in the series is $1/4$ and the common ratio is $(z-1)/2$.  Of course, the geometric series converges if and only if $|(z-1)/2|<1$.  I haven't checked to see whether the equation is actually true.